# Spring Boot project jar command line execution failing

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jax-ws

I have created a Spring Starter project in STS tool to implement a java web service using Jax-ws and apache cxf . This project is working properly in my development environment when I am executing as "Spring Boot App" .

I need to execute it in production server . For that I have executed Runa As -> maven install which created the -0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar under target folder .

Then tried to execute java -jar -0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
It was initially giving class not found exceptions which were resolved by adding dependency on javax.xml.ws, javax.jws, javax.xml,jaxb-api in pom.xml.

It is now failing after the following warning :

2018-05-18 20:41:18.394  WARN 24151 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpoint' defined in class path resource [com/xxxx/yyyyyyy/config/WebServiceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'endpoint' threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException

After this it is stopping tomcat followed by many other exception . This same class WebServiceConfig.class worked for Spring Boot App execution . The code is given below .

```
package com.xxxx.yyyyyyy.config;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.xxxx.yyyyyyy.ExampleWsImpl;

@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {

        Endpoint endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus,new ExampleWsImpl());
        endpoint.publish("/ExampleService");
        return endpoint;

    }
}
```

Can someone please throw some light here to understand the reason behind the error .